# App on iOS 17 is getting OutOfMemory crashes

Tags: ios, memory, out-of-memory, ios17

The exact same build that was running fine in older versions of iOS is getting now a spike of OutOfMemory crashes on iOS 17.

I have went through Instruments and I can't find any memory leaks. Has anything related to memory management changed on iOS 17?

Comment: Is it a single location/call in the code that gives OOM or are you getting it in various locations?

Comment: I am seeing this through error reports (so no stack trace for OOM), I couldn't replicate it myself yet.

Comment: Hey any/news updates?

Comment: @AlexanderKhitev not really, I shaved memory usage and tweaked a bunch of stuff but I wasn't able to reduce this kind of crashes

Comment: @displayname - is this issue fixed? I am too facing.